# Diodon does not save anything copied to the clipboard

Tags: 14.04, clipboard

I am on 14.04 and just installed Diodon via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diodon-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install diodon unity-scope-diodon
```

and restarted but when I CTRL+C copy some text, nothing gets saved into the Diodon clipboard history. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Diodon 1.1.0 uses Zeitgeist as storage so when Zeitgeist is disabled nothing will be added to the history.

If you want to disable Zeitgeist but still want Diodon to add items you can go to "Security & Privacy"  -> "Files & Applications" settings and simply disable all include possibilities but leave Documents activated. See screenshot.

[image: Allow Diodon to store clipboard items]

Comment: thanks Oliver. it works after I Log Off and back in. is this info shown on some tutorial for Dioden?

Comment: there was a similar discussion here https://bugs.launchpad.net/diodon/+bug/1309623 but a blog post with more details should follow.

Comment: for more details see blog post http://esite.ch/2014/08/11/why-does-diodon-not-save-anything-to-the-clipboard-history/

Comment: I didn't even need to reboot...I just turned the Record file... and included only Documents! Thanks!